# Theming GTK CSS doesn't work properly

Tags: python, css, gtk, themes, gtk3

I have a Python/Gtk+3.0 application with the following layout

```
Gtk.Window
  Gtk.Box
    CustomClass : Gtk.ScrolledWindow
      Gtk.ViewPort # created automatically
        Gtk.Grid
          Gtk.Box # many of this
        Gtk.ScrollBar # created automatically
        Gtk.ScrollBar # created automatically
```

Now I'm triying to theme it, but it doesn't work, I want to change the background of my Customclass but I want change it with CSS.

I'm trying:

```
#CustomClass,
#CustomClass > GtkBox,
#CustomClass > GtkViewPort,
#CustomClass > GtkGrid,
GtkScrolledWindow GtkGrid {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Where can I find a good reference for theming? When I look in themes installed in my system I see things like

```
.custom-class { /* ... */}
GtkSomething.custom { /* ... */}
```

How do I apply this kind "class" selector to my elements from code and from glade, I'm using both.

Answer (score 1):

### Theming GTK 3.0 with CSS

These objects were taken from your example layout above:

- Gtk.Window
- Gtk.Box
- Gtk.ScrolledWindow
- Gtk.ViewPort
- Gtk.Grid
- Gtk.Box
- Gtk.ScrollBar

If you look on the https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/#classes page, you can find the full list of **GTK 3.0** class names.

Your objects are included in that list as these classes:

- Window
- Box
- ScrolledWindow
- Viewport
- Grid
- Box
- Scrollbar

You can click on any class name in the list to open a page that goes into detail about the object for that class. You'll get information like the ancestors and descendants, examples of use, etc. What you're looking for is CSS selectors. If there are CSS nodes and subnodes for you to use as selectors for that class, they'll be detailed in the **CSS nodes #** section of the page, sometimes with additional related information you may need.

After clicking on each of the classes from your example above, you'll come up with these CSS selectors for use in the **gtk.css** file to target the objects in your layout:

- window
- box
- scrolledwindow
- viewport
- grid
- box
- scrollbar

*Note that as you'll sometimes see, the mapping isn't always direct between class names and CSS selectors, so not all of the classes in the list can be used as selectors. For example, the **CSS nodes #** section of the **ListBox** class page shows that there is no **listbox** CSS selector for styling the **Gtk.ListBox** object. To target that object, you'd use the **list** selector and to target each row, you'd use the **row** selector.*

Answer (score 0):

You can give that object, which implements from CustomClass, a Name, so that it can be selected by name. Like this:

```
main_scrolled_window = CustomScrolledwindow()
main_scrolled_window.set_name('main_scrolled_window')
```

then, in css:

```
'''
#main_scrolled_window{
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
'''
```

It is not too bad to do like this, event though I don't know how to theme a custom widget class directly.

Comment: The name of the custom class is 'CustomClass' I have prefixed with 'set_name'